# Lexicographical string comparison using loops

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I want to lexicographically compare two strings of equal length, containing Latin letters. Uppercase and lowercase letters are considered same.

Here is my code:

```
string in1,in2;
    getline(cin,in1);
    getline(cin,in2);
    int l=in1.length();

    for(int i=0;i<l;++i){
        in1[i]=tolower(in1[i]);
        in2[i]=tolower(in2[i]);
    }

    int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;++i){
        sum1=sum1 + int(in1[i]);
        sum2=sum2 + int(in2[i]);
    }
    if(sum1==sum2)
        cout<<"0"<<endl;
    if(sum1<sum2)
        cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    if(sum1>sum2)
        cout<<"1"<<endl;
```

However, this gives errors on certain test conditions.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compare function

```
int x = in1.compare(in2);
if(x == 0)
     cout<<"Both are Equal";
else if (x > 0) 
    cout << in1 << " is greater than "<< in2 << endl; 
else
    cout << in2 << " is greater than "<< in1 << endl;
```

Comment: And soon, in C++20, `auto x = in1 <=> in2` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it wrong because it doesn't consider the order of characters. For example "ab" and "ba" will get the same sum.

Comment: Great dissection of the problem. To make this a good answer, you should offer a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcmp` with the `std::string` C string extractor `c_str()`. Here is a complete working solution that does it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s1("aabad");
    std::string s2("abaaaaaaa");
    if (strcmp(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str()) <  0) std::cout << "s1 <  s2\n";
    if (strcmp(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str()) >  0) std::cout << "s2 <  s1\n";
    if (strcmp(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str()) == 0) std::cout << "s1 == s2\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can surely use the operators provided by the standard library for `std::string` types:

```
operator==
operator!=
operator<             lexicographically compares two strings
operator>             (function template)
operator<=
operator>=
```

For more information, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).